# Openni_tracker question

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker

How do I bring up the Prime Sense User Tracker viewer? I ran rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker and it looks like it published to /tf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39209/openni_tracker-question/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It sounds like you're trying to get skeleton tracking? Take a look at this thread, it may be useful...

http://dougsbots.blogspot.com/2012/02/ros-kinect-skeleton-tracking.html

Also, I had written something up on my blog a while back about skeleton tracking using the same components (thanks Pi Robot!). You can look at that here... scroll down to the section on skeleton tracking though to save some time

http://dougsbots.blogspot.com/2012/02/ros-kinect-skeleton-tracking.html

Best,
Doug

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0